# Center a dynamically generated table cell in the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on an employee directory that allows a user to search for an employee and show information about them in a tree/org-chart type layout. I'm using [Google's Org Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?hl=en) code to draw the chart. It displays each employee's contact card in a `<td>` with managers and subordinates above or below it in a different `<tr>`. The output looks something like this:

[image: Orgchart1]

If an employee has more than a small handful of subordinates, the user has to scroll horizontally in order to see them all. Not a problem.

My problem is that if there are more than 10 or so, you lose sight of the employee you searched for completely and have to scroll right until you find them:

[image: Orgchart2]

This seems like it would be annoying. I tried just dropping a `<a name="anchor">` into the card and jumping to it on page load but it only scrolls far enough to **barely** put it on screen.

Ideally, it would center the card, putting it right in the user's focus.

**Is there a way to jump directly to the employee in question when the page loads?**

If it helps, here's a code snippet for what an individual card looks like:

```
<td>
    <h1>Mike</h1>
    <div class="cardBody">
        <img src="Images/stock1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;" /> 
        <table class="data" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></td>
                <td><span style="color:red;">President</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-building"></i></td>
                <td>Administration</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></td>
                <td>Home Office</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></td>
                <td>Ext. 2402</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></td>
                <td><a href="mailto:email@address.com">Send Email</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Google ORg chart already centers it. Are you using any custom CSS that align it differently? I don't get your question

Comment: @renanlf - It does center it. But **because** it centers it, when there are more child nodes than fit in the window horizontally, it pushes the parent node to the right to maintain an overall centering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little confused on what you have tried to far. Does jQuery work for you? If so, [this solution](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) seems simple enough.

```
$(container).scrollTo(target);
```

Now if you can pass your "target" through a url query. You should be able to parse and use it like so:

*Note: This assumes you have a url like www.website/searchpage.html?i=targetID*

*Also: This is setup to work with IDs so change the code if you need to work with classes.*

```
var params;    
function parseURLParams(url) {
        var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
            queryEnd = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
            query = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1),
            pairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&"),
            parms = {}, i, n, v, nv;
    
        if (query === url || query === "") {
            return;
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            nv = pairs[i].split("=");
            n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
            v = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);
    
            if (!parms.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                parms[n] = [];
            }
    
            parms[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
        }
        return parms;
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
   params = parseURLParams(window.location.href);
   $("#Container").scrollTo("#"+params.i);
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Edit:
I realize you want it to be centered which is going to be a little tricky. You're going to need your container to be much larger(or infinite?) than required for it to fit all the data, and then scroll to the position of the desired element, plus an offset for half the container's view able width, and half the element's width. Might just want to create an invisible element with an absolute position when you calculate this number. Then move the element to this position, and finally the screen to this element.

Comment: I'm going to call this the answer. I used `$('#container').outerWidth() / 2 - $(window).width() / 2)` to grab the necessary scroll position and the `scrollTo()` you suggested to smoothly get me there. Also, since the table was dynamically generated, I had to drop the code in a `setTimeout()` to force the scroll to happen after the table was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the URL to so it jumps to the div with a specific ID. For example in the card code you posted you'd change the div to this:

```
<div class="cardBody" id="mikeCard">
```

Then change the link to the page to

```
<a href="employees.html#mikeCard">Link to page with Mike's card centered</a>
```

or if you want to link to that part from the same page just do

```
<a href="#mikeCard">Jump to Mike's card</a>
```

Comment: I already tried an internal link. It doesn't center it. It only scrolls far enough to show the item being linked to.